# Dual Boot Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 8 using Windows Installer

Tags: boot, windows-8

I really want to avoid making costly mistakes. How can I do this using the Windows Installer provided by Ubuntu.

Specifically, I'm afraid to get past the "reboot" screen during the installation process.

Comment: Why are you afraid about getting past the 'reboot' screen?  Can you explain your question a little better?

Answer (score 0):

The windows installer will not touch your drives, it will simply add a option to the windows boot menu. ubuntu will boot but it runs off of a disk image. pretty safe.